# How to update account using PUT with devise_token_auth?

Tags: devise-token-auth

I'm using devise_token_auth gem in my Rails 5 API application.
For testing all devise token routes i use Postman.
When I try to update a user account using PUT method on route "https://localhost:3000/auth", I fill the body of request with that:

```
{"data":{"name":"user1"}}
```

or

```
{"user":{"name":"user1"}}
```

the response comes back with `"success"` status and JSON representation of a user with the same (not updated) `"name"` attribute.

Does it mean that devise_token_auth does not provide such functionality and a have to overrride the `User` controller and a model ?

Answer (score 0):

the first step is get tokens valids and after add the headers in the PUT request and add in the body this json format:

{
 "name": "newname"
}

The URL for login in devise token is:

http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in

[image]

For update params for example name copy in the body and do not forget add the values in the header

[image]

[image]

I hope you solve your problem